# PHP query based on sessions

Tags: php

HI I wanted to know how to restart a session in php. When I use the code given below in one of my pages it would work for the 1st time. When I refresh the page the previous session continues. So how can I start a new session when the page reloads?Thanks for the quick response.**INCLUDED WHOLE CODE TO MAKE THINGS CLEAR**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Shopping Cart</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="products-wrapper">
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <div class="products">
    <?php
    //current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
    $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM shop ORDER BY product_code ASC");
    if ($results) { 

        //fetch results set as object and output HTML
        while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
        {
            echo '<div class="product">'; 
            echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';           
            echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'.$obj->product_name.'</h3>';
            echo '<div class="product-info">';
            echo 'Price '.$currency.$obj->price.' | ';
            echo 'Qty <input type="text" name="product_qty" value="0" size="3" />';
            echo '<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
            echo '</div></div>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->product_code.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

    }
    ?>
    </div>

<div class="shopping-cart">
<h2>Your Shopping Cart</h2>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["shop"]))
{
    $total = 0;
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($_SESSION["shop"] as $cart_itm)
    {
        echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
        echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span>';
        echo '<h3>'.$cart_itm["name"].'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="p-code"></div>';
        echo '<div class="p-qty">Qty : '.$cart_itm["qty"].'</div>';
        echo '<div class="p-price">Price :'.$currency.$cart_itm["price"].'</div>';
        echo '</li>';
        $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
        $total = ($total + $subtotal);
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    echo '<span class="check-out-txt"><strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong> <a href="view_cart.php">Check-out!</a></span>';
    echo '<span class="empty-cart"><a href="cart_update.php?emptycart=1&return_url='.$current_url.'">Empty Cart</a></span>';
}else{
    echo 'Your Cart is empty';
}

?>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All your suggestions dont seem to work

Comment: Why do you want to use `sessions` then ? If you want the variables to be destroyed on page reload ?

Comment: Place this code at the end of your file `<?php @session_destroy(); ?>`

Comment: @SyedQarib When i try your code , the shopping cart empties when i try to add another product.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove session first and start again

```
if(session_id() != '' || isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_destroy();
  session_start();
}
else {
  session_start();
}
```

Comment: Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in C:\wamp\www\zeromilez.com\Shop.php on line 2

Comment: @SKRocks yes check out my comment

Answer (score 0):

You may use session_destroy function in the end of your file.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once("config.php");

    /*your code*/

    session_destroy();
?>
```

> > session_destroy — Destroys all data registered to a session
> >
> > bool session_destroy ( void )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `session_destroy();` to destry a session and then you can start a new one

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
@session_destroy(); // destroy session if exists
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_destroy(); // destroy session if exists
}

session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>
```

**UPDATE 3 :**

If you want to unset only $_SESSION['shop'] after using it

```
if(isset($_SESSION["shop"]))
{
  // your code

  unset($_SESSION['shop']); // unset your session after using it
}else{
    echo 'Your Cart is empty';
}
```

Comment: Nope, then I guess it has nothing to do with sessions

Comment: what the problem have you got?

Comment: the session still continued. check out my full code and let me know

Comment: do you want to unset only `$_SESSION['shop']` after using it

Comment: when i do that and remove an item from the shopping cart no page loads, the page stays blank white

Comment: then you should unset your session when you click on empty cart

Answer (score 0):

You have to destroy the session after your event.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");

//after doing your task with the session variable destroy session
   session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: nope an error says your are trying to destroy an uninitialized session

Comment: Ok. what is your session time out?? how many minutes/hours?
you want to start a new session in every page load??